Outlook Add-In Manifest Installation Fails with WebApplicationInfo Block
I am developing an Outlook add-in and encountering an issue when trying to include the  block in my manifest file. Without this block, the add-in installs smoothly. However, when I add the  block, I receive the following error during installation:
`Installation failed
Sorry, we can’t complete this operation right now. Please try again later.`

Here is the relevant part of my manifest file:
`<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"        xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>d09dd777-38cd-77d7-b2db-3535c315d22c</Id>
    <Resource>api://d09dd509-29cd-36d7-b2db-3566c402d55c</Resource>
    <Scopes>
      <Scope>User.Read</Scope>
      <Scope>Mail.ReadBasic</Scope>
      <Scope>Mail.ReadWrite</Scope>
    </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
  <!-- Further configurations -->
</VersionOverrides>`

What I have tried:
Ensuring the XML structure is correct and validated against XML schema.
Checking namespace declarations and ensuring they match those required by Office add-ins.
Reviewing the application registration in Azure to ensure it matches the IDs and resources declared in the manifest.
My environment:
Outlook on Mac OS (Desktop client)
Outlook Web Access (via Chrome)
I'm looking for suggestions on what might be causing this installation error and how to fix it. Specifically, if there are known issues with the WebApplicationInfo block or nuances in its configuration that might typically lead to such an error.
